# Compare two columns of a dataframe against 1 column of another dataframe and if matches print the row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two csv files read into 2 dataframes:

df1:

```
 Aend   Bend

  A      B

  C      D
```

df2

```
 node_name Alarm

   A        alarm1

   D        alarm2
```

List =["NTP", "LOS"]

I want to check for row1 in df1 if columns Aend or Bend matches with node_name in df2. If yes take the corresponding row from df2 and have to check the condition

`if df2[Alarm] contains any value from **List** :

```
  print "YES"
```

else:

```
  print "NO"
```

Similarly check for row2 .
What would be the best way to do this.

Comment: Thank you. I have updated my question. Please let me know if you need any further details

Comment: List contains few strings that I want to check against. If these string is found in Alarm I want to add Yes into a new column or add No to that column.

Answer (score 0):

There appear to be 2 issues you are trying to address:

1. Filter `df2` according to matching `node_name` in `df1`.
2. Add a new column to `df2` depending on whether `Alarm` is in an input list.

For the first part, you can construct a list of in-scope values and use `pd.Series.isin`:

```
# combine A_end and B_end values
vals = df1.values.ravel()

# filter df2
df2 = df2[df2['node_name'].isin(vals)]
```

For the second part, you can use `numpy.where` to create a new series based on a condition:

```
import numpy as np

L = ['NTP', 'LOS']

df2['NewCol'] = np.where(df2['Alarm'].isin(L), 'Yes', 'No')
```